# Entity Framework Code First and Code First Migrations for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In March 5, 2015 Oracle provides a tutorial

Link to [Tutorial](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:4703302542561:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:11003,,24)

This tutorial demonstrates how to use Entity Framework (EF) Code First with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)

Following the steps and running the project I am getting this error.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.MemberInfoExtensions.GetValue(MemberInfo memberInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(String providerTypeName, String providerInvariantName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__2(ProviderElement e)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DbProviderServices()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetServiceAsServices(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServices(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass6.<GetServices>b__5(IDbDependencyResolver r)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.Lock()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.<.ctor>b__1()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.InternalConfiguration.get_Instance()
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer[TContext](IDatabaseInitializer`1 strategy)
       at NuGet.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Visual Studio\Tutorials\NuGet\NuGet\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices' threw an exception.
       Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
       TypeName=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices
       StackTrace:
            at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.get_Instance()
       InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
            HResult=-2146233054
            Message=Could not load type 'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
            Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
            TypeName=OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass
            StackTrace:
                 at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProviderSettings.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFProviderSettings.IEFProviderSettings.get_TracingEnabled()
                 at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFProviderSettings.InitializeProviderSettings[T]()
                 at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices..ctor()
                 at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices..cctor()
            InnerException:
```

I'm seeing this error Message=Could not load type 'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Haven't been able to find anything related to this error anywhere.  Bellow is the generated app.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="LocalOracle" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PDBORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=ZR;Password=mypassword;Data Source=LocalOracle"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Is anyone getting this same error message, and if so has anyone found a work around or solution.

Comment: I experience the same issue on some machines with pre-installed Oracle drivers. Very interested if you found a solution here.

Comment: solution is not to use Code First with Oracle - too buggy